# How jquery can call controller method from outside

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i am new in mvc but have good experience in webform. when we call any page method by jquery then page method has to be static and must have webmethod attribute in asp.net webform but in case of asp.net mvc when we call any controller method by jquery then that method can be as normal like public method. so i just need to know that how it is possible for jquery to call controller method from outside. i search this by google but found no discuss on this issue. so please anyone who have in depth knowledge please discuss this in detail. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just like requesting any ASP.Net-MVC web page synchronously. It responds essentially the same way for synchronous and asynchronous requests.

It will work because you have:

- Defined the return type of the controller method as `ActionResult` or any type that inherits from it , like `ViewResult` or `JsonResult`,
- Ensured the returned value of the method to be of this same type (of course -- or you'd get compile-time error!) e.g.:

  ```
      return View(myModel);  //View() returns a ViewResult obejct.
  ```
- Placed this method inside an object that inherits from the System.Web.Mvc.Controller class.
- Mapped a route in Global.asax that matches the URL of the the request and routes it to the specified controller & action

ActionResult defines only one public method signature:

```
public abstract void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context);
```

And the framework defines a concrete version for each variant of ActionResult. But you don't really need to know the inner-workings of ExecuteResult().

The MVC framwork does all the coordination, while giving you lots of entry-points to re-configure the defaults (conventions).  It sets up  the ControllerContext, calls ExecuteResult(), creates all the default HTTP headers (which you can modify from inside the controller if you need to)  for you, etc.

Comment: u said ActionResult defines only one public method signature. what r u trying to say. a controller may have many public method.

Comment: what people try to mention using keyword ActionResult as a return type of any public method.

Comment: when we request any url then who take the first control over that request at server end. is it routing or controller.how routing code understand which controller need to invoke. how controller understand which view need to invoke. mvc engine create instance of controller.

Comment: ActionResult is an abstract class, and represents the required return type for a method in a controller to be invoked in response to an HTTP request. The class documentation (use your object browser in V.S. if you have it), only defines one method: ExecuteResult(). You can have other methods in your controller, but only those that return this type are Action Methods.

Comment: Routing controls which controller and action gets invoked by a particular URL. Read up on the basics of routes to understand this, then come back and ask more specific questions if you have them.